# What advice would you give to someone who doens't usually have breakfast?

Tags: weight-loss, breakfast

I'm on a weight loss journey. I don't take breakfast in the morning since I'm 11-12 (I'm now 24). I am starting to realize that this may have been a mistake. The thing is that I don't like feeling heavy in the morning.

As such, what would you recommend for me during the morning (i.e. what should I have for breakfast)?

From what I've gathered from the internet, most breakfast recommendations often involve lots of things (fruit, yogurt, juice, etc.), which I consider to already be too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If eating breakfast makes you feel uncomfortable, and you aren't suffering any obvious problems from not eating it, such as fatigue or hunger prior to your first meal interfering in your morning schedule, or reducing your energy if you workout in the morning, then by all means feel free to continue not eating breakfast.

"Breakfast is the most important meal of the day" was just a marketing slogan made up by Kelloggs.